# My visibility_toggle is not working as i want it to

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```
<article class="col1 pad_left1">
    <div class="box1">
        <div class="box1_bot">
            <div class="box1_top">
                <div class="pad">
                     <h2>CLIENTS</h2>

                    <button style="background:url(images/box_top.jpg)  center top no-repeat; width:100%; text-align:center; padding:5px; color:white;" onclick="toggle_visibility('demo1');" id="C4M">Consultants4Manpower</button>
                    <div id="demo1" style: "visibility:hidden;">
                        <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="down">
                            <img src="images/CII logo.png" height="80px" width="80px" alt="">
                            <img src="images/Rotary logo.gif" height="80px" width="80px" alt="">
                            <br/>
                            <img src="images/Tie logo.png" height="80px" width="80px" alt="">
                        </marquee>
                    </div>
                    <hr/>
                    <button style="background:url(images/box_top.jpg) center top no-repeat; width:100%; text-align:center; padding:5px;" onclick="toggle_visibility('demo2');" id="corporate">Corporate Training</button>
                    <div id="demo2" style: "visibility:hidden;">
                        <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="down">
                            <img src="images/CII logo.png" height="80px" width="80px" alt="">
                            <img src="images/Rotary logo.gif" height="80px" width="80px" alt="">
                            <br/>
                            <img src="images/Tie logo.png" height="80px" width="80px" alt="">
                        </marquee>
                    </div>
                    <hr/>
                    <button style="background:url(images/box_top.jpg) center top no-repeat; width:100%; text-align:center; padding:5px;" onclick="toggle_visibility('demo3');" id="EPD">English & PD Training</button>
                    <div id="demo3" style: "visibility:hidden;">
                        <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="down">
                            <img src="images/CII logo.png" height="80px" width="80px" alt="">
                            <img src="images/Rotary logo.gif" height="80px" width="80px" alt="">
                            <br/>
                            <img src="images/Tie logo.png" height="80px" width="80px" alt="">
                        </marquee>
                    </div>
                    <hr/>
                    <button style="background:url(images/box_top.jpg) center top no-repeat; width:100%; text-align:center; padding:5px; font-color:white;" onclick="toggle_visibility('demo4');" id="P4E">Paterns4Education</button>
                    <div id="demo4" style: "visibility:hidden;">
                        <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="down">
                            <img src="images/CII logo.png" height="80px" width="80px" alt="">
                            <img src="images/Rotary logo.gif" height="80px" width="80px" alt="">
                            <br/>
                            <img src="images/Tie logo.png" height="80px" width="80px" alt="">
                        </marquee>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e.style.display == 'block') e.style.display = 'none';
    else e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

The problem i am facing is when i load the page all four sections shows the images scrolling at the same time.I want is when i go to the page no image-scrolling is visible.when i click on 1 say consultants4manpower then only images under that div becomes visible  scrolling down.and further when i click on the 2nd the previous 1 become invisible and second gets visible.
Look at the link:
http://shubhamenterprises.education/about.html

Comment: so the whole problem is that the previous divs aren't becoming invisible after you click a different button?

Comment: yes and also when we open the above link you might have noticed that all four div are visible.I want them visible only when i click on the specific button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of places, you have given:

```
style:"visibility: hidden;"
```

The above code is wrong.

Since you have tagged it with jQuery, I would do something different using jQuery.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".button").next().hide();
  $(".button").click(function() {
    $(".button").next().slideUp();
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.button {
  background: url(images/box_top.jpg) center top no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<article class="col1 pad_left1">
  <div class="box1">
    <div class="box1_bot">
      <div class="box1_top">
        <div class="pad">
          <h2>CLIENTS</h2>
          <button class="button">Consultants4Manpower</button>
          <div id="demo1">
            <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="down">
              <img src="images/CII logo.png" height="80px" width="80px" alt="">
              <img src="images/Rotary logo.gif" height="80px" width="80px" alt="">
              <br/>
              <img src="images/Tie logo.png" height="80px" width="80px" alt="">
            </marquee>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <button class="button" id="corporate">Corporate Training</button>
          <div id="demo2">
            <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="down">
              <img src="images/CII logo.png" height="80px" width="80px" alt="">
              <img src="images/Rotary logo.gif" height="80px" width="80px" alt="">
              <br/>
              <img src="images/Tie logo.png" height="80px" width="80px" alt="">
            </marquee>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <button class="button" id="EPD">English & PD Training</button>
          <div id="demo3" style: "visibility:hidden;">
            <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="down">
              <img src="images/CII logo.png" height="80px" width="80px" alt="">
              <img src="images/Rotary logo.gif" height="80px" width="80px" alt="">
              <br/>
              <img src="images/Tie logo.png" height="80px" width="80px" alt="">
            </marquee>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <button class="button" id="P4E">Paterns4Education</button>
          <div id="demo4" style: "visibility:hidden;">
            <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="down">
              <img src="images/CII logo.png" height="80px" width="80px" alt="">
              <img src="images/Rotary logo.gif" height="80px" width="80px" alt="">
              <br/>
              <img src="images/Tie logo.png" height="80px" width="80px" alt="">
            </marquee>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: still there is a problem when i click on the next button the privious one still remains visible.i want is when i click the next button the previous one get invisible.

Comment: @RajatGoyal Yeah, you can do that.

Comment: Thank You for your valuable help.

Comment: one thing i noticed is once i start clicking any of the button at last any one of them remains active like when i click them again they don't come back to their original state.

Comment: I am waiting for your reply Sir.

Comment: Sir i have a further query.Say when i click on consultants4manpower it shows the images scrolling.when i click on it again it doesn't hide it back.it toggle up and again down showing the scrolling div.

Comment: What? I don't understand.

Comment: when i click on any of the four that is consultants4manpwer or corporate training etc they show their respective div where they have images scrolling down,say i clicked on corporate training.when i click on it back the toggle doesn't slide up hiding the scrolling.I want the toggles to slide up back when i re-click on it.

Comment: @RajatGoyal Sorry was busy... I will check and will surely update it. Don't worry, I am gonna fix it off... `:)`

Comment: sir i am waiting for your reply

Answer (score 0):

wrong:

```
<div id="demo3" style:"visibility:hidden;">
```

better:

```
<div id="demo3" style="visibility:hidden;">
```

best:

```
<style>
#demo3{
visibility:hidden;
}
</style>
```

although even there you are mixing `visibility:hidden;` with `display:none;` which is never a great idea